# Refresh sub frame in frameset using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to refresh a sub frame after the submit button is clicked on a different page. I have this working for two frames in the same frameset but the top frame will not reset the menu frame or sabre frame? I have seen a few examples around but I'm not getting it.

Here is my code

"Index page"

```
    <frameset frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" rows="60px,80%">
    <frame name="top" id="top" src="./top.php" name="top" scrolling="no">
        <frameset frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="420px,70%">
            <frame name="menu" id="menu" src="./menu.php">
            <frame name="sabre" id="sabre" src="./sabre.php">
        </frameset>
</frameset>
```

"The submit on the top page"

```
'<input onclick="parent.menu.menu_refresh()"
```

"javascript on menu page"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function menu_refresh(){
    setTimeout(
      function() 
      {
        window.location.reload();
         }, 2000);
    } 
</script>
```

By the looks of it parent term in the submit button is not referring back to the right level and cant find the menu page. Like I said this works when refreshing sabre page from menu and vice versa, but not for top page to menu or sabre.

Comment: This question has been viewed 38 times I cant believe I have stumped everyone???